# Gradle, BUG! BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64

Tags: gradle

This bug occured once I tried changing something in my Gradle File. I am using intelliJ and SDK20 and JavaFX and have programmed in this project for a while and already changed some things, for example dependencies. Everything worked fine, but today I wanted to change the sourceSets and as soon as i wanted to build it, the error occured. Funnily, as soon as I remove all changes from the gradle file, all spaces etc. included, so that the file is exactly the same as the last build, it works. I am so confused... I also read, that this Error occurs also when the Gradle Version does not support the Java Version, but I am using Gradle 8.0.2, so that is not the case, especially because it also worked before.

gradle.properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'application'
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.8.10'
  id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
  id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'org.nico'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

ext {
  junitVersion = '5.9.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
  mainModule = 'org.nico.spz'
  mainClass = 'org.nico.spz.SpzApplication'
}

[compileKotlin, compileTestKotlin].forEach {
  it.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'  }
}

javafx {
  version = '17.0.6'
  modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
  implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2')
  implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc11:21.1.0.0'
  implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.28'
  implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0'
  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
  testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()  }

jlink {
  imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
  options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
  launcher {
    name = 'app'
  }
}

jlinkZip {
  group = 'distribution'
}
```

```
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\nicol\spz_app\dev\app\spz\Spz\build.gradle' (C:\Users\nicol\.gradle\caches\8.0.2\scripts\6m45hhgir19mni06r8mnit1dv).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64
```

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Spz'.
    
    ... 168 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:199)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287)
    ... 193 more
```

I do not know If it is allowed to post that long Exceptions, but maybe one of you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by switching to Gradle version 8.1.1. I do not know why i worked before but at least it works now!